# CSS condensed monospaced font

Tags: css

I have a lot of data (in form of plain text) to read from txt files and display in a small div column like 180 pixels wide.

Part of this text is preformatted with tabs, like:

```
C    1    4    1.4   6    1.5  8
HL   4.5  3    1.5   1    4    1.4
U    6    1.5  8     1    5    4.9
```

To display this part I used this code:

```
<span style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-size: 10px; white-space: pre;">
C    1    4    1.4   6    1.5  8
HL   4.5  3    1.5   1    4    1.4
U    6    1.5  8     1    5    4.9
</span>
```

but it is really very large for the div, and if I use a common font it will be displayed like:

C    1    4    1.4   6    1.5  8

So, what I would like to do is one or both of the following:

1) Use a condensed monospaced font, but I couldn't find the way.

2) Use a ttf font like Arial (or so), as a monospaced font.

I don't know what else I can do to reach the goal.

EDIT: I added a jsfiddle live example of what is the problem and what should be the result please go to http://jsfiddle.net/LCVwH/

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Comment: Courier New is perfectly OK . The "Not OK" part is your HTML syntax.

Comment: There is a total of three double quotes in there. That can't be good.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It was my mistake because of a copy/paste from the actual CSS which is correct and defined elsewhere. I wanted to make it simple for the example and I forgot to change quotes. In my local version the example is correct, but the whole preformatted row is too large for the container, what I want is to have a preformatted row with monospaced font, but with a condensed font, so that the whole thing is less wide in total.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088922/custom-monospaced-terminal-font-iosevka-for-your-web-projects

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-size: 10px; white-space: pre;">
```

Is how that should be.

Using `"` you are opening and closing the style. So when you were setting the font you were closing the style.

Comment: Thanks, it was a copy/paste mistake to built the example, please read the previous comment for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Is adding `overflow:auto;` to containing div an option?
I can guess that sometimes your text will anyway overflow div.

For me, text from example is not overflowing div only at `font-size:9px;`, which is a little bit small for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't use overflow:auto; because it should be all readable with no scroll.